# ADO Continuous Deployment for PowerBi Desktop Projects PBIP

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, cicd

Microsoft only has this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/projects/projects-build-pipelines) for ADO Continuous Integration build pipelines but nothing for Continuous Deployment pipelines.

I'm trying to find some examples or links to anything that can steer me towards creating ADO CD pipelines.

Googling hasn't helped.